# Allow users to see their own acceptance rate

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, accepted-answer

Back in the days when Stack Overflow used to display a user's acceptance rate, I used to use it for only one purpose. Finding my own questions which I haven't accepted yet. I used to pride myself on having a green 100% acceptance rate. If there was a particular question which was answered but I wasn't satisfied with the answer, I would start a bounty on it.

Now, I understand why the acceptance rate feature was removed. Seeing other peoples acceptance rate is bad because it would either discourage people from answering question or prompt them to write a comment urging the user to accept more answers. This is clearly bad and I'm not in favor of bringing that back.

However, being able to see your own acceptance rate is very useful. First, it's a motivator to accept more answers or to start bounties on questions which do not have enough attention. Second, it should help users easily find those questions which have been answered but which they haven't accepted yet.

Currently, I need to go through the list of all my questions to find those which have been answered but not accepted. It's not difficult, but it is time consuming when you have several pages of questions. It would be nice to click on your acceptance rate and be taken to a page which lists all your questions which have been answered but not accepted.

Comment: Questions you asked with no accepted answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0

Comment: Glad to see that I still have an almost 100% acceptance rate. Anyway, so I just need to type `is:q user:me hasaccepted:0` into the search bar. Where can I learn more about advanced search filters?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: You can also use my [Advanced Search UI](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011) userscript.

Comment: Ok, search allows you to find them. However, having a small indicator could be a nice reminder for the many users that leave their questions without accepted answers. Do you have any screenshot of how this used to look like?

Comment: @Berriel [Q&A with example image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160080/155739). [Feature removal post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/155739).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks. These links provide a lot of context, and I tend to agree with [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136959/380585), which is basically what the OP here is talking about.

Comment: @Berriel Me too.